# Why main doesn't re-execute if I change user state? (Beginners project)

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-scripts

### APP.JS

```
function App() {

const users = [{...}, {...}] //This is array of users;

const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(users[0]); 
const [usersArray, setUsersArray] = useState(users);

const updateUser = (user) => { const index = usersArray.findIndex((usr) => (usr.username =     user.username)); 

users[index] = user;

setUsersArray(users);
setCurrentUser(users[0]);
console.log(currentUser);
};

return ( 
<div className="transactions-page"> 
<Header user={currentUser} /> 
<Main user={currentUser} users={usersArray} onTransaction={updateUser} /> 
</div> ); }

export default App;
```

---

Well main won't re-execute. To be precise, when certain deposit form is filled this should push into user movements array. When it push into user movements, it should update users. I did that logic. Because Main displays some logic, it needs to re-execute again but it won't even if this logic re-executes whole app. Regards

Comment: Where did you added that deposit form? In `Main`? If you aim to re-render `Main` with some form submission in `Main`, then you should pass down state fn's callback like this-
`<Main settingUsers={setUsersArray} />`

Comment: Well actually form component is nested in two more child components after, but through all of them I sent this "onTransaction" which updates user and users array state. Then It should go rerender app and set current user to updated user.

Comment: I found out that it doesn't re-execute app.js for some reason.